# How to select anaconda environment for jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Starting notebook from under environment does not help:

```
(py35) dims@calculon:~/Design/RAD$ jupyter notebook
[I 19:50:24.226 NotebookApp] JupyterLab alpha preview extension loaded from /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterlab
JupyterLab v0.27.0
Known labextensions:
[I 19:50:24.227 NotebookApp] Running the core application with no additional extensions or settings
[I 19:50:24.229 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/dims/Design/RAD
[I 19:50:24.229 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 19:50:24.229 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
```

gives

[image]

while

```
(py35) dims@calculon:~/Design/RAD$ python
Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 13 2017, 11:22:58)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import treelib
>>>
```

I.e. `treelib` package is not available under jupyter notebook, while it is available under `py35` environment.

How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

from terminal or cmd do the following:

```
conda install nb_conda
```

That will make the conda kernel available from jupyter notebook. You will have to exit jupyter and start it again. All other conda environments are now available from jupyter nootebook too.